# Caret in <input> tag is over block

Tags: html, css, forms, input, internet-explorer-11

This is really crazy bug! 
Look at this screenshots below 
In Internet Explorer 11 when I`m scrolling down while input is focused, caret is located over header (the input element is under header, everything is good).

General markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <div class="form">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}

input {
  margin-top: 200px; 
}
```

Screenshots: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xu1O.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DalJN.png

Link to a file on my Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KW1ztPbMXFNfzzNmsYBYnBnl_BEarafU/view?usp=sharing

Codepen: https://codepen.io/wrangler53/pen/JBPZby

Just open it in Internet Explorer 11

How to fix it?? Input and caret shoud be under the header. z-index doesn`t help

Comment: Please provide codepin or your full page code so we could help you. Screenshots is not enough. Thanks

Comment: Sure, just open it in Internet Explorer 11. Codepen: https://codepen.io/wrangler53/pen/JBPZby.Link to a file on my Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KW1ztPbMXFNfzzNmsYBYnBnl_BEarafU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to post a reproducible example here in the question. Here's the text from the flagging options - "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._"

Comment: it is not a bug, it is same in chrome too, if you position any element fixed, no matter what you do that would stay wherever you place it, and since there is no position to your input element that is going to scroll below the fixed element, if you want to see it over the div if you apply position to the input

Comment: Jismon Thomas, I can`t reproduce this bug in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I have added your code in the snippet with the positioning

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
      .wrapper {
        height: 1000px;
      }
      header {
        background: red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 10;
      }
      input {
        margin-top: 200px;
        position:absolute;
        z-index: 5;
      }
  </style>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header></header>
    <div class="form">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This input should be under the header... I`ve already changed z-index to 5 for input and 10 for header. The same problem :(

Comment: i also swapped the z-index, but it seems to be working for me, can you check the updated snippet above.

Comment: Just tried, this works for Chrome on desktop but not for Chrome or Safari on iOS. Perhaps avoid using this if you are trying to solve the issue with iOS devices.